# Unity 2019.3 : "Crash On Android Phone"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, native, il2cpp

I have built AAB (for ARM & ARM-64) then test it to my Android Smartphone, but I found it crash.

By Inspecting the log I found below error (using HTC U11, API Level 26):

```
Build fingerprint: 'htc/ocndugl_00401/htc_ocndugl:8.0.0/OPR6.170623.013/1002308.10:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 31372, tid: 31556, name: Loading.Preload  >>> com.apps.mygame <<<
signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000007b44  x2   0000000000000005  x3   0000007dad1fe1d1
    x4   000000004e524157  x5   000000004e524157  x6   000000004e524157  x7   00000000004e5241
    x8   0000000000000083  x9   346b4f359488495f  x10  346b4f359488495f  x11  0000000000000000
    x12  0000000000000000  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000000000000000  x15  0000007e351c8000
    x16  0000007e3341f2e8  x17  0000007e333c0e04  x18  0000000000000000  x19  0000007dad1fead8
    x20  0000000000000000  x21  0000007e14bfc840  x22  0000007e1428c11c  x23  0000007dad1ff588
    x24  0000007e14c36000  x25  0000000000800101  x26  000000000014d618  x27  0000007e110ef700
    x28  0000007e110ef010  x29  0000000000000008  x30  0000007e1428be84
    sp   0000007dad1fea60  pc   0000007e333c0e0c  pstate 0000000000000000
backtrace:
    #00 pc 000000000006ae0c  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
    #01 pc 000000000064ae80  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #02 pc 000000000064b390  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #03 pc 000000000027fa58  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #04 pc 000000000027fdf4  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #05 pc 00000000003035d0  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #06 pc 000000000030701c  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #07 pc 00000000002fff90  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #08 pc 0000000000329b80  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #09 pc 0000000000334628  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #10 pc 000000000032bf00  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #11 pc 000000000032c4e0  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #12 pc 0000000000276b40  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #13 pc 0000000000278488  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #14 pc 00000000002782d4  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #15 pc 0000000000278240  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #16 pc 00000000002cd5b8  /data/app/com.apps.mygame-dztW0fQOeFKAoF2N3WRWqw==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
    #17 pc 00000000000677a4  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
    #18 pc 000000000001f2a4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

I read on Unity Forum it caused by Graphic Issue so need to disable OpenGL es 3. I have tested it but still failed.

Note, I'm using below plugin (All are latest) :

- Unity IAP
- Google Admob
- Firebase

Also, I'm using Unity **2019.3.12f1** (almost latest)

Any Idea?

Comment: I'm also having the same crash, did you fix it?